# How do you find the free resolution of the module $M$ and of $F/M$ where $F=(K[x,y])^3$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

$M$ is a module generated by $$f_1=(xy,y,x), f_2=(x^2+x,y+x^2,y), f_3=(-y,x,y),f_4=(x^2,x,y).$$ We're to use the lex ordering with $x<y$ and $e_1>e_2>e_3$, where terms are given preference over position.

Also, how am I to interpret the answer I get using singular? Working with the commands `resolution s=sres(std(m),0);` and `resolution s=res(m,0);` I get, respectively, the following outputs that I don't know how to make sense of:

[image]

I'm very new at this and would greatly appreciate any help that is provided. Please include as much detail in your answer as possible.

Comment: There are three separate questions here that you could be asking, and I think you should pick one that would most like answered, just to make the task easier for answerers: (1) How does a person go about finding a free resolution? (2) How does a computer algebra system go about finding a free resolution, i.e., what are the algorithms and how do Groebner bases fascilitate them, and (3) How does a person use a computer algebra system to find a free resolution?  Also, could you cut/paste the singular output? I might be able to explain that bit for you.

Comment: @Aaron I was initially more interested in getting an answer to 1. But I think I understand the computational part of the problem. I'd still like to know the answer to 3. I've edited my question to include Singular output.

Comment: The outputs you provided are somewhat incomplete, in that what they tell you are the ranks of the modules in a free resolution, but not the maps between them (which are represented by the arrows). They are slightly confusing to read because they use a separate line for the exponent, so you might not realize they mean e.g., $r^6$. But the numbers on the top are the ranks, and the numbers on the bottom are book keeping so you know how far into the resolution you are.

Comment: As far as a human finding a resolution, the problem can be difficult in general. The issue is that finding the kernel of a map is harder over a general ring than a field. For nice modules over nice rings, there may be constructions that you can use (e.g., Koszul resolutions), but in general there may be a lot of eyeballing whether you have found generators for the kernel at each stage. This means that different people can easily come up with different free resolutions, but the beauty of homological algebra is the information we want is independent of those differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding a free resolution can be a difficult task by hand, because the simple linear algebra task of finding the kernel of a map given by a matrix is no longer simple when the base ring isn't a field.  That said, modulo the problem of being able to say for sure that you have found a complete set of generators for the kernel of a map (which the computer does using Groebner bases, but which is difficult by hand as far as I know), here is how you find a free resolution.

Let us start with $R^3/M$.  There is an obvious surjection $R^3\to R^3/M$, whose kernel is $M$.  Because $M$ was specified using $4$ generators, we have a surjection $R^4\to M$ sending the standard basis elements of $R^4$ to the given generators of $M$.  Thus, the beginning of our resolution looks like:

$$\cdots \to R^4 \to R^3 \to R^3/M\to 0.$$

Here is where things get tricky, because we have run out of information given by our presentation of $M$.  We need to find a set of generator for the kernel of our map $R^4\to R^3$.  It doesn't matter what set we take, and different choices will give different resolutions, but any two resolutions will be related to each other in such a way that the differences will cancel out for the computations we do with free resolutions.  The singular output (if I'm reading it correctly) suggests that we can find a single generator for the kernel, and since our ring has no zero zero divisors, any non-zero map $R\to R^n$ will be injective, so we can finish off our resolution

$$0\to R \to R^4 \to R^3 \to R^3/M\to 0.$$

I should note that even though we have not written out what the maps are, the maps do matter and cannot be ignored.  The information on the ranks in the resolution is only a part of the resolution, and is not sufficient to do many of the useful calculations (e.g., Ext and Tor) that resolutions are used in.

I should also note that had the process not ended where it did (by finding a place where our map onto the kernel was injective), we would have just continued on in the same way: take our last map, find generators for the kernel, and generate a new map by sending the basis elements of a free module onto the generators of the kernel.  Sometimes, this process goes on forever.  As an exercise, you should find a free resolution of $\mathbb Z/(2)$ as a module over $R=\mathbb Z/(4)$.

Another instructive exercise might be to find a resolution of $R/(x,y,z)$ where $R=k[x,y,z]$.  There is a particularly nice one where the ranks are $1,3,3,1$, but this example should be just involved enough (in terms of finding the kernels of the maps) that you can appreciate why the task is annoying to do by hand, but it should still be very tractable.